# Checing item existence in dynamo table with Python

Tags: python, flask, get, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

having some problems with checking item existence in dynamo table..code so far :

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index1():
    name = request.form["fullname"]
    get_res=requests.get('api-url',json=name)
    temp=get_res.json()
    get_res=temp['body']
    return get_res
```

Lambda get_item func :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        get_response=table.get_item(
                        Key={
                            'name':event['name']
                        }
            )
        res=get_response
    except:
        res={
            'result':'not in DB'
        }
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': res
    }
```

result im getting ( even if input name is in DB ) :

```
{
  "result": "not in DB"
}
```

**i think i somehow managed to go around it..**

```
get_res = requests.get('https://g7ry7a4ix6.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/prod/req', json=item)
    temp = get_res.json()
    try:
        if temp['body']['Item']['name']:
            pass
    except:
        res = requests.post('api-url', json=item)
    return render_template('reg.html', name=name, phone=phone)
```

Comment: You may be getting a different exception(not resource not found exception). Can you try catching specific exceptions and handle them accordingly? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: hmm..i read the link but couldnt understand how to solve this..